# How to add Item to SqlDataSource databound list

Tags: .net, asp.net, data-binding, asp.net-3.5, sqldatasource

I am lazy - and I am using a SQLDataSource to populate my dropdownLists.

The Databind event for the databound objects is called before the Page.PreRender so I am doing something like this in the PreRender eventHandler:

```
private void InitializeDropDown()
        {
            this.myDropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select something --"));
        }
```

I know I can set AppendDataBound items to true and hardcode my custom item in the markup but before reverting to that I'd like to understand why what I am doing is not working.

It usually works when I bind stuff dynamically like this:

```
myDropDown.DataTextField = "whatever";
myDropDown.DataValueField = "ID";
myDropDown.DataSource = GetStuff();
myDropDown.DataBind();
myDropDown.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select something --");
```

What I am doing should be equivalent - only difference is I am using a SQLDataSource.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` for the dropDwonList and it works like charme!
I thought it was supposed to be used only in presence of hardcoded list items in the markup. I was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Put your insert line on the OnSelected method of the datasource

myDropDown.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select something --");

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selected.aspx

Comment: nice - so basically that's the only way of doing it programmatically with a sqlDataSource? I still dont understand why if I bind it dynamically I can call Insert right after the Databind call. What's the difference between what I am doing and handling the   OnSelected method of the SqlDataSource?