# Adding Item to DataBound Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, list, drop-down-menu

Yes, I have read most of the topics here, but I can't find an answer that works.

I have Three drop-down lists. The first is databound to grab distinct experiment names. The user selects, page posts back, and the second drop-down menu displays distinct time points. This is where I need help. I need to add an item to THAT drop-down list whose ID, DataTextField, DataValueField are all TimePt.

Seems simple, but I can't get it to work.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                TimePt.DataSource = TimePTDD;
                TimePt.DataValueField = "TimePt";
                TimePt.DataTextField = "TimePt";
                TimePt.DataBind();
                TimePt.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select---", "0"));
                TimePt.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
```

I'm missing sometthing.

Comment: This should work. Are you getting any compilation error?

Comment: I'm not getting anything at all. My page loads and the second dropdownlist just says

12
72
192

It should say --Select-- ... 12...72...192.

If I use AppendDataBoundItems, it does what i want, but when I change the first dropdown list, then the other time points get added on to the TimePt drop down list.

Answer (score 5):

Set `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` on your dropdown list and it should work.

Here's a similar question: [How to add Item to SqlDataSource databound list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551957/how-to-add-item-to-sqldatasource-databound-list)

And another one about potential duplicates using this method and a workaround for it: [Dropdownlist AppendDataboundItems (first item to be blank)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730555/dropdownlist-appenddatabounditems-first-item-to-be-blank)

Comment: It won't do what I'd like it to do. I tried that and it works, but whenever I go back and choose the first drop down list, I get duplicate values in the second drop down list (which is where I want the "SELECT" to be.

That link also doesn't help me because I try it and it says I don't have a method named "MyList" which is what I named it.

Comment: Did you intend to use if (Page.IsPostBack) rather than if (!Page.IsPostBack) in your page load?

Comment: I intend to use IsPostBack because when you select the first drop down list, the page loads and the 2nd drop down list populates based on what's selected from the first drop down list.

Answer (score 3):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            TimePt.DataValueField = "TimePt";
            TimePt.DataTextField = "TimePt";
            var times = TimePTDD.ToList();
            times.Insert(0, new {TimePt="0",TimePt="--Select--"});
            TimePt.DataSource = times;
            TimePt.DataBind();
            //TimePt.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ExpAnalysisName" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="DropDownEXP" DataTextField="ExpAnalysisName" 
            DataValueField="ExpAnalysisName" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack=true>
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select an Experiment</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DropDownEXP" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SGMD3_DataBase %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT ExpAnalysisName FROM VW_Data">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="TimePt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="TimePTDD" DataTextField="TimePt" 
                DataValueField="TimePt">
        </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TimePTDD" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SGMD3_DataBase %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT TimePt
    FROM VW_Data
    WHERE ExpAnalysisName = @ExpAnalysisName">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:FormParameter FormField="ExpAnalysisName" Name="ExpAnalysisName" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

So you can have a reference.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're specifying the `DataSource` in two different ways - The `DataSourceID` in your markup as well as manually setting the `DataSource` in your codebehind. Try removing the `DataSourceID` from your markup and see if that helps.

It's been a little while since I've used ASP.NET too much, but I have a feeling your `DropDownList` is rebinding after the `Page_Load` which would replace your previous binding.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need it to do when I change the first drop down list, but I need "-select-" in the TimePt drop down list without having duplicate values as a result of rebinding that list because the data from the first down menu changed.

Comment: This shouldn't generate duplicate values as `AppendDataBoundItems` is not set to true.

Comment: No, it shouldn't because I turned it off, but if I turn it on, then it will cause duplicate values, but I will get -- Select -- to stay if I use <asp:ListItem text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>, but I want this item to appear always, regardless of what I choose from the first drop down menu and then the subsequent items be dynamic based on what was selected :).

Comment: The thing is here is that some experiments have three time points, while some have one or two.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is this is a page lifecycle issue. Per MSDN, [each data bound control whose DataSourceID property is set calls its DataBind method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

I think the values are getting bound to the dropdown twice. First, when you manually bind and append the extra item in Page_Load and then the datasource is being bound inside the Page_PreRender event.  Try bringing your Page_Load code into Page_PreRender.  Hopefully the order helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `OnDataBound` event of `DropDownList` control, and put your code behind there.
That you way you can combine `DataSourceID` with code behind.